# Increasing clipPath size causes lagging

Tags: android, android-canvas, live-wallpaper

I'm increasing the size of the clipPath in a loop. Also inside the loop is another loop which creates a few more clipPaths which I use to draw with lowered alpha so that I get a transition effect. But as the size of the clipPath increases, the transition becomes slow and lagging.

It's something like this

```
int size = 5;
Paint p1 = new Paint();
Path path = new Path();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    path.addCircle(centerX, centerY, size, Path.Direction.CCW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
    path.reset();
    int incr = size;
    while (p1.getAlpha() != 0) {
        incr -= 1;
        p1.setAlpha(p1.getAlpha() - 5);
        path.addCircle(centerX, centerY, incr, Path.Direction.CCW);
        canvas.clipPath(path, Op.UNION);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, p1);
        path.reset();
    }
    size += 10;
}
```

Desired Result

[image: Gradient]

I know this is a bad approach but this is all I could think of.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints from [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) that might be applicable:

> The following list describes known operations that are not supported
> with hardware acceleration:
>
> `Canvas.clipPath()`
>
> [...]
>
> **Don't create render objects in draw methods**
>
> A common mistake is to create a new Paint or a new Path every time a rendering method is invoked. This forces the garbage collector to
> run more often and also bypasses caches and optimizations in the
> hardware pipeline.

Also, I've read/heard somewhere that anytime you modify a path, a mask is generated and reuploaded to the GPU (?), so you shouldn't keep modifying them often. So yes, that code is probably not running fast.

You might be interested in these videos:

- [Google I/O 2011: Accelerated Android Rendering](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9S5EO7CLjo)
- [Google I/O 2012 - For Butter or Worse: Smoothing Out Performance in Android UIs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8m9sHdyXnE)

**Edit**: I don't know an actual alternative, but if there's no other way than using paths, you could keep an array of them, without modifying them. If the animation has many frames, though, that would probably mean a lot of memory.

Comment: Well, then could you give me an idea about how I could achieve the effect avoiding those changes to the path.
I've added a picture to the post.